# Horizontal page scroll in chrome mobile browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I create this [website](https://travelenter.com/). When I test this website on mobile with `chrome browser` found that my website has Horizontal scroll.

I use this `css` files in my `website` :

```
bootstrap.min.css, soap-icon.css,
font-awesome.min.css,
animate.min.css,
settings.css,
jquery.bxslider.css,
flexslider.css,
jquery-ui-1.8.14.css,
style.css,
updates.css,
responsive.css
```

---

Used jquery frame works :

```
jquery-1.11.1.min.js,
    modernizr.2.7.1.min.js,
    jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js,
    jquery.placeholder.js,
    jquery-ui.1.10.4.min.js,
    bootstrap.min.js,
    bootstrap-datepicker.min.js,
    bootstrap-datepicker.fa.min.js,
    pDate.js,
    jquery.bxslider.min.js,
    jquery.flexslider.js,
    jquery.stellar.min.js,
    waypoints.min.js,
    FarsiType.js
    theme-scripts.js,
    scripts.js
```

How can I solve this problem.Please advice[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue because of the animation property. you can simply fix this.

```
html { overflow-x:hidden; }
```

Comment: OK this is right But with  one change.I use this code only for mobile device screen size .If i use by default in large screen my page has two scroll bar. Thank you.